# how to use thread with navigation drawer fragments?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

**Context:**
I am new to android. I have created a navigation drawer with fragments.  When I run my code the app works but the choreographer says:

> ** frames skipped, heavy work is done in main thread.

**The Problem:**
The App became slow when I move to a fragment layout where there is more data.  I searched for how to solve this problem and I learned using threads will solve the issue but I am so confused to use it.

Can anyone help me?

**The Code:**

```
package com.example.venkatesh.settaiboyz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}


@Override
public final void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = home_fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = member_fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = photo_fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = event_fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = about_fragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */

    public static Fragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_facebook:
            Open_facebook();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_twitter:
            Open_Twitter();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

//Anvar

```
public void OpenActivityAnvar(View view) {

    setContentView(R.layout.anvar);
    ImageButton b;
    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call_anvar);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+919841463562"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sms_anvar);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", "+919841463562");
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    });

    b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mail_anvar);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);//common intent
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:mailtoanvar8055@gmail.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

//Main menu list

public void Open_facebook() {

    Uri webpage = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/settaiboyz");
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    startActivity(webIntent);
}

public void Open_Twitter() {

    Uri webpage = Uri.parse("https://www.Twitter.com");
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    startActivity(webIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: First you need to identify what's causing the frame skip. It could be a coding problem which will not work on a thread anyway.

Comment: None of this code looks like it could possibly be causing the problem. It's all mostly boilerplate/template stuff. You are almost certainly looking in the wrong place.

Comment: tell me how to load images and image buttons in a separate thread. It will reduce the work in the main thread right?

Comment: by the way thank you so much for your responses @ Pedro Oliveira , Josepth Roque